# ReferenceError: __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__ is not defined after npm run build with Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite

I get this error when `npm run build` the project. This error sometimes appears, sometimes disappears after restarting the browser. Users of the site have the same problem.

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import path from 'path';


export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel([
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
        ]),
    ],
    resolve: {
      alias: {
          '@' : path.resolve(__dirname, './public/assets'),
      },
    },
    server : {
        hmr: {
            host : 'localhost'
        }
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            external: 'NonExistingPath'
        }
    }
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "type": "module",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.5",
        "vite": "^4.4.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
        "@vuepic/vue-datepicker": "^7.4.0",
        "apexcharts": "^3.45.0",
        "epic-spinners": "^2.0.0",
        "floating-vue": "^2.0.0-beta.24",
        "laravel-vue-pagination": "^4.1.1",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "vue": "^3.2.36",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.4",
        "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.4",
        "vue3-toastify": "^0.1.13",
        "vuex": "^4.0.2",
        "vuex-persistedstate": "^4.1.0"
    }
}
```

I tried updating and rolling back npm packages, but that didn't help. I tried changing the `vite.config.js` file, setting `devtools: false`. It did not help.

Also try

`const store = createStore({ devtools: false, })`

But it didnt work. It is broke before hitting my app.js file.